# ffmpeg unable to open mipi camera

Tags: linux, command-line, ffmpeg, camera

I am trying to use ffmpeg to open mipi camera but it gives the following error

video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x55a6df3790] Not a video capture device.
/dev/video0: No such device

However, when I use VLC it works fine.

I am not sure what is wrong with the ffmpeg here. [Error while opening camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkoiE.png)

Comment: Did you verify that you have the correct `/dev/video` number?

Comment: yup... its correct and I can use VLC (4vl2) to open camera

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the device type is "Video Capture"?
I have same issue but My device type is "Video Capture Multiplanar".

Comment: Its a video capture multiplanar device type. What difference does it have to video capture? And what is the solution to open this camera from ffmpeg?